# How to update each DB record with a different value based on id using Perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a hash which contains all computed users' exam grades (users of the system are students in my case), where `user_id` is the key of the hash, and the grade is the corresponding value. This hash has more than 50,000 elements. I want to update the database with these computed grades.

#### My *first attempt*

```
my %grade_of = compute_grades_hash( ... );   # Some logic to compute grades
my $dbh = DBI->connect( ... ) or die( ... ); # DBI parameters are hidden in this sample
my $sql = "UPDATE User SET grade = ? WHERE id = ?";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
foreach my $user_id ( keys %grade_of ) {
    $sth->execute( $grade_of{$user_id}, $user_id );
}
```

But, if I am right, this causes more than 50,000 queries to be executed, which means more than 50,000 trips to the database (Feel free to correct me in this statement if what I am assuming is wrong.)

#### So I wrote this *second attempt*

```
my %grade_of = compute_grades_hash( ... );   # Some logic to compute grades
my $dbh = DBI->connect( ... ) or die( ... ); # DBI parameters are hidden in this sample
my $sql = build_query ( \%grade_of );
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

sub build_query {
    # Builds a string in the followig form:
    #     UPDATE User
    #     SET grade = (case when user_id = 10 then 96
    #                       when user_id = 14 then 92
    #                       when user_id = 26 then 85
    #                       ... 
    #                  end)
    # So it generates a very long query-string for the 50000 records

    ...
    return $sql_query;
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is this the right solution for the case?
2. Does the very long SQL statement affect query performance?
3. Is there any limitation on query length in Perl DBI and/or MySQL?
4. Is there any more elegant solution ? Am I missing a built-in functionality
   which I may use for instance ?

By the way, just in case the answer is depending on the following info, here are my system specifications for completeness:

> ```
> $ mysql --version 
> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.25, for Linux (x86_64)
>
> $ perldoc -m DBI | grep -m1 VERSION 
> $VERSION = "1.621";
>
> $ perl --version 
> This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux
> ```

Comment: It is very easy to absorb the situation from a question, and to answer in terms of how one would approach it in the same circumstances. That approach ignores the Stack Overflow rules, and looking back you don't appear to have a solid question here. Your numbers 1 and 4 are off topic on the grounds of being opinion-based. 2 is inevitably a "yes", but perhaps not in the sense that you meant. That leaves 3 and, while the limit depends on the driver, it appears to be undocumented for MySQL and it's safe to say that a 3MB query like yours is "too long".

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried running either of these?

Your first attempt is correct. That is the sort of thing that databases are made for. Your second version is likely to be much slower. Depending on how the SQL engine is optimised, but regardless of how you formulate your SQL, your database *still* has to do 50,000 updates. Your second attempt forces it to do a lot more work deciding what those updates are

You can expedite the process, and avoid the possibility that some records are updated and others not, by using a *transaction*

Before you start updating the database, call

```
$dbh->begin_work
```

and when they are all done, you need

```
$dbh->commit
```

This will create a list of changes to be made to the table and finally *make* those changes when you call the `commit` method

You should be working with a test database anyway, so I suggest that you set one up that contains a manageable amount of data that will give your results fairly quickly. Then you can *try* both of your options, as well as any more that you think of, and know for sure how they behave

Answer (score 1):

This could possibly be faster:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Updates` (
           `user_id` ... NOT NULL,
           `grade`   ... NOT NULL
       );

INSERT INTO `Updates` VALUES
       ( ..., ... ),
       ( ..., ... ),
       ...;

ALTER TABLE `Updates` ADD UNIQUE `user_id`;

UPDATE `User`
  JOIN `Updates`
    ON `User`.`user_id` = `Updates`.`user_id`
   SET `User`.`grade` = `Updates`.`grade`;
```